# Nested SQL.promise() callback in Javascript

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, promise, callback

I want to write a nested callback JavaScript in order to use the subsequent ID's of the INSERT statements in the different SQL tables. My code looks as follows:

```js
db.promise().query(
     // create Place with auto-generated PlaceID
      `INSERT INTO Place (Street,PLZ) VALUES('${street}', ${plz})`
    ,
    (err,result) => { 
      db.promise().query( 
          // insert User using PlaceID
          `INSERT INTO User (PlaceID, Name, Created_On) VALUES(${result.insertID}, '${name}',current_timestamp())`
        ,
        (err,result) => { 
          // insert Account using UserID
          `INSERT INTO Account (UserID, Email, Password, Created_On) VALUES(${result.insertID}, '${email}', '${pwd}', current_timestamp())`
        }
      );
    }
);
```

However, when trying to run this with Node.js it says `Error: Callback function is not available with promise clients`. 
Do you have a solution to retrieve the insert IDs for the following INSERTS?

I've also tried with `.then((result)=>{..})` which seems to work but the result.InsertID is always undefined?

```js
// create place with auto-generated PlaceID
db.promise().query(`INSERT INTO Place (Street,PLZ) VALUES('${strasse}', ${plz})`)
              .then((err,result) => { 
                if(err)throw err;
                // insert User using PlaceID
                db.promise().query(
                    `INSERT INTO User (PlaceID, Name, Created_On) VALUES(${result.insertID}, '${name}',current_timestamp())`)
                  .then((err,result) => { 
                    if(err)throw err;
                    // insert Account using UserID
                    db.promise().query(`INSERT INTO Account (UserID, Email, Password, Created_On) VALUES(${result.insertID}, '${email}', '${pwd}', current_timestamp())`)
                  });
              }).catch((err)=>{console.log(err)});
```

Comment: Why are you using `db.promise().query()` instead of `db.query()`?

Comment: You process the results of a promise with `.then((result) => ...)`.

Comment: @Barmar when I do it without promise() it says HTTP header is set before client. I tried with `.then((result) =>..)` but this gives me a nhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it has to be `result.insertId` instead of `result.insertID` and then it doesn't return NULL anymore..

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing the two styles. If you want to pass an error-first callback, you shouldn't use the `promise()` API.

```js
// INCORRECT: If you're using promise(), you use .then,
// not an error-first callback.
db.promise().query(/* ... */,
    (err,result) => { 
      /* ... */
    }
);

// CORRECT: Delete the promise() to use an error-first callback.
db.query(/* ... */,
    (err,result) => { 
      /* ... */
    }
);
```

You *can* use promises, but if you do, then you won't use parameters `(err, result)`. The function passed to `then` uses a single parameter, `result`, and `err` will be handled *either* in a chained `catch` as you have below, or (infrequently) [in a second function passed to `then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#parameters).

```js
// INCORRECT: The function passed to `then` should never take two arguments.
db.promise().query(/* ... */)
  .then((err,result) => { 
    /* ... */
  }).catch((err)=>{console.log(err)});

// CORRECT: The function passed to `then` only takes a `result`.
// If there were an error in your outer query, it would call
// your `catch` handler.
db.promise().query(/* ... */)
  .then(result => { 
    /* ... */
  }).catch((err)=>{console.log(err)});

// ALSO CORRECT: The call to `then` can also receive an error handler,
// but it will only catch errors in your outer `query`. If your `then`
// handler throws any errors, this style of chaining won't catch them.
db.promise().query(/* ... */)
  .then(result => { 
    /* ... */
  }, err => {
    /* ... */
  });
```

Comment: Thank you. I've already noticed this, though. My mistake why `result.insertID` returned NULL was actually because it has to be `result.insertId` without the capital D.